# SQL server resets UDP port 1434 connections

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

Attempting to connect to a named instance on SQL server.
Attempt is made in port 1434 (SQL Browser)

PCap shows the connection acknowledged and reset.

SQL Browser service is running
TCP/UDP port 1434 is open

Is there something I should be looking for on the SQL server that would be causing this?

I am able to telnet to port 1433, but not 1434

Comment: See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297506/remote-computer-cant-connect-to-instance-with-backslash/297516#297516) for a PowerShell script to remotely test SQL Brower connectivity to verify UDP port 1434 is open.

Comment: Thank you,
I'm not sure what is happening, but UDP port 1434 (SQL Browser) is not open, and no matter what we do, it remains closed.
We need to reboot the server anyway, so I'm hoping that will kick it into gear.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to telnet to port 1433, but not 1434

Telnet uses TCP/IP, which is why you can use it to test for TCP/IP connectivity.  The SQL Browser service uses UDP, so you can't use telnet to test.